# converting QdateTime to normal python dateTime?

Tags: python, datetime, pyqt, pyqt4, qdatetime

I have a lot of existing code that just uses the normal `dateTime` class in python, however in upgrading my program I am using the `QtGui.QdateTimeEdit()` class, but that class returns a `QdateTime` object that seems to be incompatible with the normal `dateTime` object.

So, is there a sane way to convert `QdateTime` to normal python `dateTime`? Other then breaking it into its parts and recreating a normal `dateTime` object from that? I am using PyQt4 with Python 3.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`QDateTime` has a `toPyDateTime` method which will return regular `datetime` objects.

```
In : from PyQt4 import QtCore

In : QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR
Out: '4.8.6'

In : QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR
Out: '4.7.4'

In : now = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()

In : now
Out: PyQt4.QtCore.QDateTime(2011, 12, 11, 20, 12, 47, 55)

In : now.toPyDateTime()
Out: datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 11, 20, 12, 47, 55000)
```

Comment: thanks, I guess i missed that in the Docs, now i feel stupid but thanks anyways for showing me that! ;-)

Answer (score 21):

**[PyQt - use `.toPyDateTime()` on QtCore.QDateTime object](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdatetime.html#toPyDateTime)**

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import QDateTime
>>> qdate = QDateTime(2012, 12, 20, 11, 59, 59)
>>> qdate
PyQt4.QtCore.QDateTime(2012, 12, 20, 11, 59, 59)
>>> date = qdate.toPyDateTime()
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 20, 11, 59, 59)
```

**[PySide - use `.toPython()` on QtCore.QDateTime object](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QDateTime.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QDateTime.toPython)**

```
>>> from PySide.QtCore import QDateTime
>>> qdate = QDateTime(2012, 12, 20, 11, 59, 59)
>>> qdate
PySide.QtCore.QDateTime(2012, 12, 20, 11, 59, 59, 0, 0)
>>> date = qdate.toPython()
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 20, 11, 59, 59)
```

Comment: nice to see both variants.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(self.dte1.date().getDate())
print(self.dte1.date().toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

you only need `toString()` method  for python string